# How to generate a map of string slices from protobuf file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3, protobuf-go

As the protocol-buffers [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#map) describes:

> Each map field generates a field in the struct of type
>   `map[TKey]TValue` where `TKey` is the field's key type and `TValue` is
>   the field's value type...

I would like to set `TValue` to be a slice of string. So that in Go it generates:

```
map[string][]string
```

Considering also this note on [repeated fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#repeated):

> Likewise, for the field definition `repeated bytes foo = 1;` the
>   compiler will generate a Go struct with a `[][]byte` field named `Foo`

I'm trying to do the following:

```
message CallBackUrl {
    string base_url = 1;
    map<string, repeated string> params = 2;
}
```

But this just spits an error:

```
pb/authenticator.proto:57:26: Expected ">"
```

I could do this:

```
message StringSlice {
    repeated string slice = 1;
}

message CallBackUrl {
    map<string, StringSlice> params = 1;
}
```

Outputs:

```
type StringSlice struct {
    Slice []string
}

type CallBackUrl struct {
     Params               map[string]*StringSlice
}
```

However, in the implementation `Params` will need to be used as an [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) to build a query string. This last solution would required an additional iteration, and copying the data into a new `map[string][]string`, which I would like to avoid.

**(How) can I make protocol-buffers generate a (Go) map of string slices?** I'm using the gRPC plugin.

Comment: Not possible as of now. Your second way of doing is the current hack for now. I too came across same issue when I used it for the first time and finally used the second approach.